# I have an 120 volt light fixture in my front steps outside that was wired without a grounding wire. How do I make it safe?

Tags: electrical

I had two exterior step lights installed in front steps.  The concrete was poured but the masonry contractor forgot to connect the grounding wires.  How do I make it safe after the fact? They are 120 volt lights inside light boxes

Comment: Usually wiring through poured concete is in conduit, often ENT. Pictures of the inside of these light boxes, please? Turn off the breaker first, of course.

Comment: The implication of Ecnerwal's comment is that the ENT itself may be the ground - that's why the request for pictures of the wiring in the box. Also, if there are ground wires then it's a simple fix to connect them to the fixture itself.

Comment: @Freeman EMT would qualify but ENT is Electrical Nonmetallic Tubing.  Alphabet soup lol.

Comment: oh. :( Would like to blame lack of coffee, but I'm sure I'd had a couple by then...

Comment: But if it's ENT (smurf tube) (as is common) adding a ground should be relatively easy if the conduit was contructed correctly. OK, now to see if I can manage to take a vacation from spending too much time here, having ticked the 200K box for real. ;^) (and still no T-Shirt...)

Comment: I would replace the light's guts with 12v DC LEDs (strip, landscape, etc) and rewire the backend to provide it such.